# Powershell outputting an executable into a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell script for work that will take the output of w32tm.exe \monitor and output everything into a text file. I'm trying the following code, however something is wrong since I'm able to create the text file, but nothing is being written in it:

```
#Take output of w32tm.exe and output into a plain text file
$file = "C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\timeScript.txt"
$executable = "w32tm.exe /monitor"
invoke-expression $executable | out-file -filepath $file
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm new to Powershell so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I can get all of the data to be displayed on the console when I run this, however I want the data to be written on the text file.

EDIT 2:
I managed to get everything to finally output. I wanted to try avoiding using the > operator to write out to the text file in hopes of learning a little more on the out-file cmdlet however doing a simple invoke-expression $executable > $file managed to get the job done. I still don't understand why the cmdlet wouldn't work properly.

Comment: just using `invoke-expression $executable` give you the expected output to console? Using your code in my session, changing just the path to my profile dir it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `Invoke-Expression` isn't properly sending output to stdout?  I wouldn't expect that, but stranger things have happened.  Try running `w32tm.exe` on its own:

```
$file = "C:\Documents and Settings\a411882\My Documents\Scripts\timeScript.txt"
w32tm.exe /monitor | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Start-Process` which allows you to redirect also the error output:

```
Start-Process w32tm.exe -ArgumentList "/monitor" -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput "output.txt" -RedirectStandardError "error.txt"
```